# both if and else statements excecuting

Tags: php, if-statement

I've got a weird problem: both my if and else statements are executing. Here's my code:

```
    if ($sel_user['name'] != $name) {
        $query = "UPDATE owner SET 
                ..."
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        if (mysql_affected_rows() ==1) {
            $query2 = "UPDATE queue_acl SET 
                ..."
            $result2 = mysql_query($query2);
            if (mysql_affected_rows() ==1) { 
                $_SESSION['updates_occurred'] = true;
            } else {
                $_SESSION['updates_occurred'] = false;
            }
        }
    }

    if ($sel_user['orgId'] != $orgId) {    
        $query = "UPDATE ownerOrganization SET
                ..."
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        if (mysql_affected_rows() ==1) {
            $query2 = "UPDATE queue_acl SET
                ..."
            $result2 = mysql_query($query2);
            if (mysql_affected_rows() ==1) {
                $_SESSION['updates_occurred'] = true;
            } else {
                $_SESSION['updates_occurred'] = false;
            }
        }
    }

    if ($sel_user['date_expires'] != $colVal[0] || 
            $sel_user['admin'] != $colVal[4]) {
        $query3 = "UPDATE queue_acl SET
                ..."
        $result3 = mysql_query($query3);
        if (mysql_affected_rows() ==1){
            $_SESSION['updates_occurred'] = true;
        } else {         
            $_SESSION['updates_occurred'] = false;
        }                
    } else {
        $_SESSION['updates_occurred'] = false;    
        $message = "<i>There were no edits to apply</i>";
    }
```

When I run this, the queries are being sent and everything is being updated fine, but the "There were no edits" message is also being printed

Anyone know why?

EDIT: I do *not* want to use elseif statements; the events are not mutually exclusive. That is, if $sel_user['name'] != $name AND $sel_user['orgId'] != $orgId, it is required that *both* queries are sent

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't want to wrap everything in an if/else if statements, one could set a flag at the end of each if check.

```
if($sel_user['name'] != $name) {
     // CODE HERE
     $flag = true;
}

if(!$flag){
     $message = "<i>There were no edits to apply</i>";
}
```

It's that or you can run the if check off  $_SESSION['updates_occurred']

Comment: +1 Upon clarification of his question, it is clear the OP wants to run all three and report if none run.

Comment: That's a great suggestion -- fixed it. Thanks Tim :-)

Comment: This is really nice :)

Answer (score 8):

Instead of doing lots of ifs, you should be doing elseifs

i.e.

```
if () {


} elseif () {


} else {

}
```

hope that helps.

Comment: Definitely the right advice.  Factor your code in a way that these errors jump out at you.  This is a good step.

I suggest never writing in the `} else { ` style.  You want your `if` and paired `else if` and `else` indented at the same level.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that is not what I want. I did not use elseif statements because I do not want the updates to be mutually exclusive; more than one statement can be executed

Comment: Hi eigen, looks like Tim's got you sorted but it does make this question rather misleading.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!printf("Hello")) {
    echo "Hello";
}
else {
    echo " World";
}
```